# Looking for a Short Story Title about a Victimizing Society

Tags: story-identification, society

This story, maybe 1960s or 70s, is about a society where everyone carries a weapon, and people prey on each other.  Those who allow themselves to become victims are blamed for being weak.  After a number of infractions, they are hunted and executed while an audience silently watches.  The story ends after one such execution, and the audience response is silence.  The main characters are a young couple.  She carries a gun in the pocket of her skirt, and when she goes shopping, a friend watches while she tries on clothes.  They have dinner with a family whose son is slashed by a school mate, a little girl who tricks him.  The mother slaps the boy repeatedly because he was tricked.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember if this is a short story or a novel?  Do you remember any details of the cover?